# whats wrong with type in below code how to define type for o

Tags: mongodb, scala

type issue in below code how to define type for o if I remove instanceof then it is returning anyref how to do casting then ?

```
def toList(dbObj: BasicDBList): Array[MaxMinValues] = {
 dbObj.parallelStream().map { o =>
  //print(o)
  MaxMinValues(
    o.asInstanceOf[BasicDBObject].get(Constants.maxCitationCount).asInstanceOf[Int],
    o.asInstanceOf[BasicDBObject].get(Constants.minCitationCount).asInstanceOf[Int],
    o.asInstanceOf[BasicDBObject].get(Constants.maxSearchCount).asInstanceOf[Int],
    o.asInstanceOf[BasicDBObject].get(Constants.minSearchCount).asInstanceOf[Int],
    o.asInstanceOf[BasicDBObject].get(Constants.maxReanalysisCount).asInstanceOf[Int],
    o.asInstanceOf[BasicDBObject].get(Constants.minReanalysisCount).asInstanceOf[Int],
    o.asInstanceOf[BasicDBObject].get(Constants.maxViewCount).asInstanceOf[Int],
    o.asInstanceOf[BasicDBObject].get(Constants.minViewCount).asInstanceOf[Int]
  )
 }.asInstanceOf[Array[MaxMinValues]]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BasicDBList#parallelStream()` returns `java.util.stream.Stream<E>` which you can turn into `scala.Stream` so that your map function will take partial function.

You can use [scala-java8-compat](https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat) to turn `java.Stream` into `scala.Stream`,

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-java8-compat" % "0.9.0"
```

Then you can pattern match the result as `BasicDBObject` once without having to cast on each line.

Example,

```
import com.mongodb.BasicDBList
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject

val list = new BasicDBList

list.add(new BasicDBObject(
  "maxCitationCount", 1
))

list.add(new BasicDBObject(
  "maxCitationCount", 2
))

import scala.compat.java8.StreamConverters._

final case class MaxMin(max: Int)

def toList(dbObj: BasicDBList): Stream[MaxMin] = {
  dbObj.parallelStream().toScala[Stream].map {
    case (o: BasicDBObject) =>
      MaxMin(o.getInt("maxCitationCount"))
    //TODO handle default case
  }
}

val result = toList(list)
println(result) //Stream(MaxMin(1), ?)
```

If you want to evaluate whole `Stream`, do `Stream.toList` or `Stream.toArray`.

```
//evaluate stream
val result = toList(list).toList
println(result) // List(MaxMin(1), MaxMin(2))
```

Comment: def toList(dbObj: BasicDBList): Array[MaxMinValues] = {
    dbObj.parallelStream().map { o =>
      val basicDBObject = o.asInstanceOf[BasicDBObject]
      //print(o)
      MaxMinValues(

Comment: whats the problem with this approach then?

Comment: basicDBObject.get(Constants.maxCitationCount).asInstanceOf[Int],
        basicDBObject.get(Constants.minCitationCount).asInstanceOf[Int],
        basicDBObject.get(Constants.maxSearchCount).asInstanceOf[Int],
        basicDBObject.get(Constants.minSearchCount).asInstanceOf[Int],
        basicDBObject.get(Constants.maxReanalysisCount).asInstanceOf[Int],
        basicDBObject.get(Constants.minReanalysisCount).asInstanceOf[Int],
        basicDBObject.get(Constants.maxViewCount).asInstanceOf[Int],

Comment: basicDBObject.get(Constants.minViewCount).asInstanceOf[Int]
      )
    }.toArray().map(_.asInstanceOf[MaxMinValues])
  }

Comment: did you read my solution? I'm not using any class casting there. take a look

Comment: yes I saw that u are using pattern matching , thanks

Comment: right, is that not what you want? If you want array to `.toArray`. I just returned `Stream` in example

Comment: thanks for solution but I also want to know if I convert to scala streams in my solution and then how to convert anyref array to defined type ?if you can help me with that , it will be great

Comment: .toArray[MaxMinValues] it will work am I right after converting to scala stream

Comment: even it will directly so only i had to change to scala stream , I know ur solution is better but still I wanted to know thanks

Comment: Correct, you can evaluate stream with `toList` or `toArray`.